# AS3 Pausing child movie clips on separate frames in parent

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, movieclip

Quick Question on pausing and resuming child movie clips in a parent. My Parent movieclip has  3 other child movie clips inside of frame 1,2,and 3 (each with their own different animations) which will be called in the .as file when the circumstance arises.

However when it comes to pausing the parent movieclip, I would like to be able to return to the same frame of the child movieclip it was currently on. Example, Parent is on frame 2, the child on frame 2 is on frame 15 of its own animation, when resumed the Parent movieclip would stay of frame 2 while the child would pick off from frame 15.

At the moment the only thing i can think off would be to have two variables, one holding the current parent frame and the second holding the childs current frame, and upon resuming, go to parent frame and then  'child'.goto andplay( child frame). However would this require each child to have the same instance name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your exact setup, I believe what you want is recursive pausing and resuming:

```
function recursivePause(clip:MovieClip):void
{
    var len:int = clip.numChildren;
    clip.stop();
    for(var i:int = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(clip.getChildAt(i) is MovieClip)
        {
            recursivePause(clip.getChildAt(i) as MovieClip);
        }
    }
}

function recursiveResume(clip:MovieClip):void 
{
    var len:int = clip.numChildren;
    for(var i:int = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(clip.getChildAt(i) is MovieClip)
        {
            recursiveResume(clip.getChildAt(i) as MovieClip);
        }
    }
    clip.play();
}
```

Comment: At the moment I run something similar to this in my GameContainer clip which houses everything else. I push any clips which i will need to be paused in a Pause_array which then passes to each clip stored in it the pause command. What i was having issues with was more my lack of knowing how pausing clips on separate frames would work.    Seems aslong as i tell the parent clip to goto the correct frame first and use the correct instance name for the child, that resuming works as planned now